# How to create admin account with Passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Currently, I want to create a page with MongoDB, NodeJS and Express.

I have followed one guide on how to create a website and get an option to create an account(users). However, I would like to create my own admin panel with manually added Admin. 
I am afraid that somehow I would create an option to "app.post" and register another admin - in other words, I do not want to give the option to post more accounts. I just want to have one account. 
I am using passport-local-mongoose, passport, passport-local.

> //This is code from the Udemy course:

```
>router.post("/register", function (req, res) {

> var newUser = new User({

>    username: req.body.username

>  });

>  User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function (err, user) {

>    if (err) {

>      req.flash("error", err.message);

>      return res.redirect("register");

>    }

>    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {

>      req.flash("success", "Welcome to our website!");

>      res.redirect("/");

>    });

>  });

>});
```

> //I thought I could do it like this:

```
>var newUser = new User({

>  username: "Admin"

>});

>User.register(newUser, "VerySecurePassword", function (err, user) {

>  if (err) {

>    req.flash("error", err.message);

>    return res.redirect("register");

>  }

>  passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {

>    console.log("registered")

>  });

>});
```

> .

//After that I got some errors:

```
(node:2496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at C:\Websites\YelpCampCurrent\routes\index.js:37:5
    at promise.then.catch.err (C:\Websites\YelpCampCurrent\node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\index.js:250:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:2496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2496) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Overall, I want to create an account but no one else could create one as well. With the code I created above, I think, I could survive as it creates the account in the admin panel and after that, I think I could remove the rest of the code.